# A/B test mobile site version vs desktop with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing

I have mobile version of site on subdomain m.site.com and desktop version site.com. I want to send 50% of traffic from m.site.com to site.com and compare conversion. The problem is that right now it's almost 2 different sites, so I think I need different goal pages for m.site.com and site.com. If it possible to create such experiment at Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible and google analytics didn't require any specials steps for it.